# How do I render a *truly* custom regex error message in my Mongoose model?

Tags: regex, express, mongoose, mern

Currently I have this working in my controller method:

```
const regex = new RegExp(
      '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})'
    );

    if (regex.test(req.body.password) === false) {
      throw new Error(
        'Your password must contain at least 8 characters: At least one number,at least one lower case letter, at least one upper case letter and at least one special character, like a fullstop.'
      );
    }
```

Since best practices denote that data sanitisation must be completed in the model, I want to validate there, but can't seem to get it working with a custom error message. I've tried a few different things, most notably (in the Schema):

```
      validate: {
        validator: function (v) {
          return /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})/.test(
            v
          );
        },
        message: (props) => `${props.value} is not a valid password!`,
      },
```

The issues that I'm having with this approach is that, although you appear be setting the message value, in postman it appears to be prepended with some awful looking junk that I can't seem to get rid of I.E. "User validation failed: password: " :)

for informational purposes, I got rid of the ugly mongoose error messages on fields specified as unique, by:

```
userSchema.post('save', function (error, doc, next) {
  if (error.name === 'MongoError') {
    if (error.message.includes('screenname')) {
      next(
        new Error(
          'A user with this screenname already exists. Please try another.'
        )
      );
    } else if (error.message.includes('email')) {
      next(new Error('A user with this email address already exists.'));
    }
  } else {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Unfortunately, the same technique isn't working for 'validation' values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I finally found a solution:

```
userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (user.isModified('password')) {
    const regex = new RegExp(
      '^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})'
    );
    console.log('1', user.password, regex.test(user.password));
    if (regex.test(user.password) === false) {
      console.log('2');
      next(
        new Error(
          'Your password must contain at least 8 characters: At least one number,at least one lower case letter, at least one upper case letter and at least one special character, like a fullstop.'
        )
      );
    }
    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 8);
  }
  next();
});
```

I hope that helps somebody!